# How can I create an empty dataset using sparkcontext in Code Workbook in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

How do I create a bare minimum PySpark DataFrame in a Palantir Foundry Code Workbook?

To do this in a Code Repository I'd use:

```
my_df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame([('1',)], ["a"])
```

Comment: To expand on your example on creating an empty dataset in Code Repositories: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73406822/how-can-i-create-an-empty-dataset-from-on-a-pyspark-schema-in-palantir-foundry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code workbook injects a global `spark` as the Spark session, rather than a transform context in `ctx`. You can use it in a Python transform ('New Transform' > 'Python Code'):

```py
def my_dataframe():
    return spark.createDataFrame([('1',)], ["a"])
```

Or with a defined schema:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from datetime import datetime

SCHEMA = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('entity_name', T.StringType()),
    T.StructField('thing_value', T.IntegerType()),
    T.StructField('created_at', T.TimestampType()),
])

def my_dataframe():
    return spark.createDataFrame([("Name", 3, datetime.now())], SCHEMA)
```